# google visualization-Click event calling other google chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am trying to use google chart event listeners to make some exploding charts, like a pie chart explodes to a table which in turn explodes to some other chart.[Is there is some other way to do this would appreciate your suggestion.]

Approach > I have a pie chart which is showing up correctly on the page, on clicking any pie it should make a table (using google chart) with some different content. (my call to php page and the results returned are correct) but somehow the table chart is throwing error.

I am getting `"container is not defined"` error. I looked online for this, some folks said I need to define `google.setOnLoadCallback` so that all `divs` are loaded before the call is been made. I tried that but no luck. I know I am doing something silly, any help would be appreciated.

here is my JS, I have `m_user_div` and '`module_div'` defined in my html page.

```
    /*!ZZ
     * Column chart for Most Used Modules.
     * History
     * 2015-Aug-10
     */

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(mostUsedModules);

    function mostUsedModules(param) {

            var syshost = param.value;
            var jsonChartData = $.ajax(
                            {
                            url: "include/mostUsedModules.php",
                            data: "sys="+syshost,
                            dataType:"json", async: false
                            }
                            ).responseText;

            // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var ChartData = new google.visualization.DataTable(
                            jsonChartData);

            // Define Chart Options .
            var options = {
                    title: 'Most Used Modules (Run Time)',
                           pieHole: 0.4,
                           sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0.4/8,
                           };


            // Instantiate and draw chart.
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('module_div'));
            chart.draw(ChartData, options);

    // ***CHART IS CORRECTLY SHOWN ON THE PAGE***

            // Add our selection handler.
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

    function selectHandler(e) {
    // grab a few details before redirecting
       var selection = chart.getSelection();
       var row = selection[0].row;
       var col = selection[0].column;
       var module = ChartData.getValue(row,0);
       google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['table']});
       google.setOnLoadCallback(tableList(module));

    }

    function tableList(module) {

       //alert(ChartData.getValue(row,0) + ChartData.getValue(row,1));

       var jsonTableData = $.ajax(
                    {
                    url: "include/userList.php",
                    data: "module="+module,
                    datatype: "json", async: false
                    }
                    ).responseText;


// *** userList.php returns a valid data in json format ***

  // Create our datatable out of Json Data loaded from php call.

       var TableData = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonTableData);

       google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['table']});

       var tab_options = {title: 'List of Users Used this Module',
               showRowNumber: true,
               alternatingRowStyle: true,
               height: 20}

       // Instantiate and Draw our Table
       var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('m_user_div'));

       table.draw(TableData, tab_options);

    //location.href = 'http://www.google.com?row=' + row + '&col=' + col;

    }
```

My html page -

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="dashboard_graph x_panel">
                            <div class="row x_title">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2>Most Used Modules <small>Darter (2014-2015)</small>
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                            <li><a class="collapse-link" ><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="x_content">
                                <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google/mostUsedModules.js">
                                </script> -->
                                <div id="module_div"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- col-md -->


                    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="dashboard_graph x_panel">
                            <div class="row x_title">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <h2>Most Used Modules <small>Darter (2014-2015)</small></h2>
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="x_content">
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google/mostUsedModulesCompile.js">
                                </script>
                                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/google/mostUsedModules.js">
                                </script>
                                <div id="compile_module_div"></div>
                                <div id="m_user_div"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>  <!-- col-md -->
                </div> <!-- row -->
```

Comment: what does `document.getElementById('m_user_div')` return? what does the same line return in the beginning on the callback ?

Comment: i did a 'alert(document.getElementById('m_user_div')); and it returns 'null'

Comment: if its returning null in the beginning of the callback function ( mostUsedModules ) as well. I would confirm if the HTML is correct.

Comment: also is the m_user_div set to disabled in the html?

Comment: I guess its something related to div, module_div alert is good but m_user_div returns null. How to check m_user_div set to disabled. I and using exactly same code for both divs.

Comment: added part of html code "compile_module_div' runs absolutely fine.

Comment: er there is only id="user_div" in the html , no 'm_user_div'

Comment: sorry about that it was a typo.

Comment: FYI you have id=module_div defined before the calls to your script files, whereas id=m_user_div is defined afterwards. But if I understand correctly, this shouldnt' be a problem with the onloadcallback..anyways try moving the id=m_user_div to where the module_div is .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89940/discussion-between-kay-and-gyaani-guy).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the fix.

In function selectHandler, I need to remove

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(tableList(module));
```

then add package 'table' to the first `google.load` at the start of my JS.

This fixed the problem as I got to know that div was not getting loaded before calling JS, though this is something that I already wrote in the question (based on my search) I never knew where to hit the hammer. Also, thanks gyanni_guy appreciate your help.

It seems loading visualization again seems to reset/remove the divs that are already loaded till that point.

The first line looks something like this now

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart','table']});
```